# NextGEN Gallery still pointing to local drive

Tags: wordpress

I recently moved a wordpress site from my C: drive to a pre-production environment, linux-based machine. The site works well-ish now.

I am using NextGEN galleries there and am using custom gallery theme. This is the problem: After moving, for some reason the galleries refer to the gallery with absolute path of the C: drive, which is obviously not working since this is another machine. I looked into the database to see if there's any value starting with C:\ and indeed I found out several of them and corrected them from `C:\xampp\htdocs/wp-content/themes/subspace\nggallery\gallery-subspace.php` to `wp-content/themes/subspace\nggallery\gallery-subspace.php`. However, after refreshing the page which used the gallery in WYSIWYG editor of WP and checking its settings, it stil referred to the template on the C: drive (namely, this is on the "display galleries tab", under "Customize the display settings", it is the value of the "Template" setting).

I checked the database again and there was no path like this in it. I refreshed the page, no difference. I got irritated and went to get a cup of coffee. When I returned, I ran the database query without any modifications again and found this in the `wp_options` table, option name `"_transient_e4ae686b7454a142b0618b1ff15b38f4"`:

```
O:8:"stdClass":17:{s:2:"ID";i:4018;s:13:"post_password";s:0:"";s:10:"menu_order";i:0;s:16:"display_settings";a:20:{s:27:"override_thumbnail_settings";s:1:"0";s:15:"thumbnail_width";s:3:"120";s:16:"thumbnail_height";s:2:"90";s:14:"thumbnail_crop";s:1:"1";s:15:"images_per_page";s:2:"24";s:17:"number_of_columns";s:1:"0";s:15:"ajax_pagination";s:1:"1";s:20:"show_all_in_lightbox";s:1:"0";s:23:"use_imagebrowser_effect";s:1:"0";s:17:"show_piclens_link";s:1:"0";s:17:"piclens_link_text";s:14:"[Show PicLens]";s:19:"show_slideshow_link";s:1:"0";s:19:"slideshow_link_text";s:16:"[Show slideshow]";s:8:"template";s:73:"C:\xampp\htdocs/wp-content/themes/subspace\nggallery\gallery-subspace.php";s:19:"use_lightbox_effect";b:1;s:23:"display_no_images_error";i:1;s:18:"disable_pagination";i:0;s:17:"thumbnail_quality";s:3:"100";s:19:"thumbnail_watermark";s:1:"0";s:20:"ngg_triggers_display";s:5:"never";}s:8:"order_by";s:9:"sortorder";s:15:"order_direction";s:3:"ASC";s:10:"exclusions";a:0:{}s:13:"container_ids";a:1:{i:0;i:37;}s:22:"excluded_container_ids";a:0:{}s:9:"sortorder";a:0:{}s:10:"entity_ids";a:0:{}s:7:"returns";s:8:"included";s:20:"maximum_entity_count";s:3:"500";s:6:"source";s:9:"galleries";s:12:"display_type";s:35:"photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails";s:4:"slug";N;s:8:"id_field";s:2:"ID";}
```

Which, as you can see contains the `C:\` path again. I'm 100% positive this wasn't in the database a while ago and repeated the process with the same result (corrected this, waited a minute and it appeared again). Is it possible that this is pulled e.g. from some file?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps mentioned below:

In the wp-admin, go to "Gallery" -> "Other options" then, Click to       "Lightbox effects" tab and Click "Show advanced settings" there,       you'll find option to change the stylesheet and javascript urls.       Change from '**localhost**' to your **baseurl** or ( 127.0.0.1 ).       Then save. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i can help.

Warning : do not try on production, get a dev or appropriate local version running. Also -- can't remember using  NextGen, so my advice comes from a desire to do "best" practice in WP.

Easy try : kill cache if used such as JetPack or similar.

Regrading the `_transient` - should be able to kill -- this link [Can I remove transients in the wp_options table of my WordPress install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422574/can-i-remove-transients-in-the-wp-options-table-of-my-wordpress-install) seems to be dialed in. So if there is a cached element in the mix...bingo.

Next thing is the `C:\...stuff` rendered in the page source / html? If so, how is it rendered in the page (HTML please)? In other words, what part of the execution is writing `C:\...` to the page and why? WP has a bad habit of adding the site to the link (grr!). For example image `src` attribute will have the ``http://``` :

`<img src="http://example.com/uploads/whatev..."`

And this is written in the wp_posts table (fun migration issues esp if you change url) - so there is a slim possibility that the gallery info with the C drive ref is in the post or similar.

iD10t check: no config setting you missed in gallery? I hope there is not a 3rd party server/storage as @Hareesh mentioned!

Desperation (done this a few times) : dump the MySQL, get a large text editor and search for the string. Remember that weird stuff could be escaped as a `"` may turn into  `\"` or the use of alternative "safe" quotes. See what can be learned.

Always an option : reinstall in a new WP site and see what/how things go.

If I think of anything else I will add it, but I just spilled how I would try to dissect the issue. GOOD LUCK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [search and replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace all `C:/...` instances with the correct ones.

But be sure to make a full DB backup beforehand, in case something breaks...