# How to stop WordPress plugin from updating?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress plugin which I have modified according to my needs. When I push it to the site, it updates automatically when there is a new update overriding my changes. I want to disconnect its connection from the WordPress plugins directory so it stops updating. Which feature do I need to change?

```
<?php

/**
 * The plugin bootstrap file
 *
 * This file is read by WordPress to generate the plugin information in the plugin
 * admin area. This file also includes all of the dependencies used by the plugin,
 * registers the activation and deactivation functions, and defines a function
 * that starts the plugin.
 *
 * @link              http://www.acekyd.com
 * @since             1.0.0
 * @package           Display_Medium_Posts
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       Display Medium Posts
 * Plugin URI:        https://github.com/acekyd/display-medium-posts
 * Description:       Display Medium Posts is a wordpress plugin that allows users display posts from medium.com on any part of their website.
 * Version:           3.0
 * Author:            AceKYD
 * Author URI:        http://www.acekyd.com
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * Text Domain:       display-medium-posts
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this plugin is publicly hosted on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org):

Change the `Plugin Name: Display Medium Posts` in the comment section on top to something different and unique, e.g. `Plugin Name: Display Medium Posts - Fahad's Edition`. It won't automatically update any more.

In order for the change to take effect immediately, you need to delete `_site_transient_update_plugins` from your `wp_options` table. See e.g. [Can I remove transients in the wp_options table of my WordPress install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422574/can-i-remove-transients-in-the-wp-options-table-of-my-wordpress-install)

Comment: In my last try I changed the name of the plugin but it still got updated.

Comment: @FahadUddin Just tried it myself, you need to clear your site's transient cache - see updated answer.